# Why isn't the source std::map for std::map::merge const?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a reason why

```
template<class C2>
void std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::merge( std::map<Key, T, C2, Allocator>& source );
```

takes `source` as a reference, rather than a `const` reference?

Perhaps I'm having a senior moment here, but I don't see how `source` is changed in any way by the function, plus it's less than helpful the way it is.

Comment: The description of what merge does, on cppreference.com, will be enlightening. Yes, `source` does get modified. Quite drastically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`merge()` does, in fact, modify the source map. It's an optimized operation that executes the merge by relinking both maps' innards, transplanting the merged values from one map to another without actually copying either the key or the value, only by fiddling the internal pointers.

Hence, at the end, the source map will (usually) be just a shadow of its former glory. And it cannot be `const`, for that to happen.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `... && source` then? It's essentially a move.

Comment: It's not a move. Values with the same key are not moved out of the source map, they're left behind. But there is an overload with an `&&`, so all the bases are covered, if you don't care about the duplicates.